# How to use webp image format in HTML

Tags: html, css, image, webp

I know this is a new format for images, but I don't know how to show it in HTML.

Does anyone know how I can do that? Which browsers can show this image format besides chrome?

[sample-webp-image.webp](https://www.gstatic.com/webp/gallery/1.webp)

Comment: Read this https://developers.google.com/speed/webp/

Comment: I know its old but...

https://caniuse.com/webp

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You use webp like any image:

```
<img src="img.webp" />
```

However since it's not always supported (see http://caniuse.com/#feat=webp), you can use this to set a fallback:

```
<picture>
  <source srcset="img.webp" type="image/webp">
  <source srcset="img.jpg" type="image/jpeg"> 
  <img src="img.jpg">
</picture>
```

Comment: Thanks, but I need to use in Firefox browser and I want to dont change image format for display

Comment: There's not much you can do thought, firefox just doesn't support it yet.

Comment: Do you need the other `<source>` if the jpg one is already in the `<img>`?

Comment: @Volper Yes, you really need the second `source`, 'cause on some version of safari, it is not supported well.

Answer (score 4):

What if it doesn't find the image for the specified path, how can I show a no picture image in that case, something similar to this:

```
<img src="img.jpg" onerror="this.src = 'nopicture.gif';"/>
```

Comment: `onerror` is deprecated ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/img#browser_compatibility)).